# How to export hbase data to hdfs directory

Tags: hbase

when i m trying to export hbase table data to hdfs directory through this command:

```
$hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export <tablename> <export directory>

At the following line my jobs hangs.

2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native
2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=cloudera
2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/cloudera
2015-04-16 21:11:49,946 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/cloudera
2015-04-16 21:11:49,948 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x720eb0ac, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2015-04-16 21:11:50,004 INFO  [main-SendThread(quickstart.cloudera:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-04-16 21:11:50,011 INFO  [main-SendThread(quickstart.cloudera:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2015-04-16 21:11:50,027 INFO  [main-SendThread(quickstart.cloudera:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x14cc394917b000d, negotiated timeout = 40000
2015-04-16 21:11:50,108 INFO  [main] util.RegionSizeCalculator: Calculating region sizes for table "TBL_REVENUE_GENERATOR".
```

please give correct way to export data.

Answer (score 0):

HBase’s Export tool is a built-in HBase utility that enables the easy exporting of data from an HBase table to plain SequenceFiles in an HDFS directory.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export <tablename> <outputdir>
```

Comment: How can we specify the format? What is the default format